# Loader - Error #2036: Load Never Completed (random times)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, youtube-api

Some computers with Windows 7 are keep getting #2036 error for few or more days, and other not (everything is loaded correctly).

Its not wrong path or case sensitive file name, because it works for some and is also official YouTube code.

Using

```
var loaderReferences:Dictionary = new Dictionary(); 
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
loaderReferences[0] = loader;
```

to avoid GC didn't help.

Using

```
loader.load(new URLRequest(
    "http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&nocache="+new Date().getTime()));
```

to avoid cache didn't help.

Clear all flash cache didn't help.

Update flash player didn't help.

Flash has access to internet and could load anything else, even from different domain with success.

I read a lot in google and tried every solution I found.

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, noFile);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurity);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
```

Comment: your loader is getting garbage collected, make it an instance member.

Comment: Like in description, I already tried: Using var loaderReferences:Dictionary = new Dictionary(); var loader:Loader = new Loader(); loaderReferences[0] = loader; to avoid GC didnt helped. Is that what you mean? If not, then please show me an example. Thanks.